# don't want to write query every time while i want to calculation, how can i use variable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

```
$all_trades = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('market_id', '=', $market_id)->get();
```

I'm trying get all entries which has (col: `buy_datetime`  > col: `sell_datetime`) and (col:`buy_rate` * `quantities`).

actually trying to get this in variable. 
from `$all_trades`, how can store whole records of single column in variable?

**for example, I want to store col: `quantities` into $abc varible.**

Comment: Have you attempted something like: `$users = FinalTrade::whereColumn('buy_datetime', '>', 'buy_datetime')
                ->get();`?

Comment: I want to store col: quantities into $abc varible. @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: It seems you have two questions in your post. You use `pluck('quantities')` instead of get, or you use `get('quantities')` after the query has returned a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where raw, this method allows you to write raw sql code for WHERE statement

`FinalTrade::whereRaw('buy_datetime > sell_datetime')->get();`

Or you can try to use Database Expressions

`FinalTrade::where('buy_datetime', '>' DB::raw('sell_datetime'))->get();`

For this column `buy_rate * quantities` you can use selectRaw method

`FinalTrade::where('buy_datetime', '>' DB::raw('sell_datetime'))
  ->selectRaw('buy_rate * quantities as column1')
   ->get();`

[image]

---

```
`$finalTrades = FinalTrade::get(); 

$numbers_of_entries = $finalTrades->count(); 

$finalTrades->transform(function (FinalTrade $finalTrade) use 
($numbers_of_entries) { 
$finalTrade->result = ($finalTrade->quantities * $finalTrade->buy_rate) / 
$numbers_of_entries; 

return $finalTrade; 
});`
```

Comment: I don't want to use a lot query. I want to solve via  variable, $all_trades has everything, now  `$xyz = $all_trades->pluck('buy_rate'); like $x = array($abc * $xyz)`

Comment: But it can be faster if you do this by sql,

Comment: oh! actually, teacher said me, why are you making a lot of query every-time. You should single query for number of operations.

Comment: if you don't want can you explain me clearer what do you want to do with variables, what is your issue

Comment: This is a single query, you will execute only one sql statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177337/discussion-between-kinnari-prajapati-and-andranik).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) to get column from collection

```
$abc = $all_trades->pluck('quantities');
```

Comment: Should I do it without pluck?

Comment: Why you don't want `pluck` ?

Comment: as you are using laravel use `pluck` in core php you can do it by any loop like `foreach`

Comment: Actually I want to multiply `$abc` to another variable $xyz = $all_trades->pluck('buy_rate'); like $x = array($abc * $xyz)

Comment: Then you'll need to use `$all_trades->foreach(...)` or use `$abc = $all_trades->map(....)` see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map

Comment: you can use `DB::raw('quantities * buy_rate as newCol ')`

Comment: $all_trades = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('market_id', '=', $market_id)->select(DB::raw('quantities * buy_rate as newCol '))->pluck("newCol");

Comment: I dont want to write everytime query, ... i want to solve my operation via `$variable`